# Making a array on the basis of certain attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows:

```
  data = [
    {
"attributes": {
   "Name":"Material",
   "Code":"ABC",
   "Name":"Russia"
},
"AttributeList":{
  "Attribute":[
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"id",
        "AttributeValue":"PROD"
     }
    },
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"commodity",
        "AttributeValue":"Rice"
     }
    },
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"unit",
        "AttributeValue":"1"
     }
    }
  ]
}
},
{
"attributes": {
   "Name":"Material",
   "Code":"CDF",
   "Name":"INDIA"
},
"AttributeList":{
  "Attribute":[
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"id",
        "AttributeValue":"PROD"
     }
    },
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"commodity",
        "AttributeValue":"Barley"
     }
    },
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"unit",
        "AttributeValue":"2"
     }
    }
  ]
}
},
{
"attributes": {
   "Name":"Material",
   "Code":"DEF",
   "Name":"UK"
},
"AttributeList":{
  "Attribute":[
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"id",
        "AttributeValue":"PC"
     }
    },
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"commodity",
        "AttributeValue":"PulSe"
     }
    },
    {
     "attributes":{
        "AttributeName":"unit",
        "AttributeValue":"3"
     }
    }
  ]
}
}
    ]
```

From this array I have to have a array if "AttributeName" is "id" and AttributeValue is "PROD" and "AttributeName" is "commodity" and AttributeValue is "Rice" or "Barley". then my final array will look like this:

```
finalArray = [
{
 "code":"ABC",
 "description":"Russia",
 "unit":1
},
{
 "code":"CDF",
 "description":"INDIA",
 "unit":2
}
]
```

code value will be value of "Code", description will be "Name" and unit value will come from AttributeList having  Attribute name as Unit. How to do this?

Comment: array.reduce() function is your friend here

Comment: please add the result from the given data. and the code, you tried.

Comment: @YosiLeibman Why would you use an array reduce? I would think array map is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` combined with `Array.find()` to achieve your goal.

I would use the `JSON.parse()` method to not have to use square brackets, but if you don't want to do it, here's a code that might help:

```
let formatted = data.map((item, index, arr) => {
    let attributes = item['attributes']
    let unit = item['AttributeList']['Attribute'].find(obj => obj['attributes']['AttributeName'] === 'unit')['attributes']['AttributeValue'];
    return {
        "code": attributes['Code'],
        "description": attributes['Name'],
        "unit": unit
    }
});

console.log(formatted);
```

- You have a syntax error, one of the objects is has a dot instead of a comma after it.

Hope it helps.

---

Comment: in your code where you are checking coditions which I mentioned in question. "AttributeName" is "id" and AttributeValue is "PROD" and "AttributeName" is "commodity" and AttributeValue is "Rice" or "Barley".?

Answer (score 0):

Your object have duplicate key **Name**

```
"attributes": {
   "Name":"Material",
   "Code":"ABC",
   "Name":"Russia"
},
```

Considering no duplicate key https://jsfiddle.net/aditya76/ar7q2knh/2/

```
let ans = [];
data.map(d => {
    let isValidId = d.AttributeList.Attribute.some(x => x.attributes.AttributeName == "id" && x.attributes.AttributeValue == "PROD");
    let isValidCommodity = d.AttributeList.Attribute.some(x => x.attributes.AttributeName== "commodity" && (x.attributes.AttributeValue == "Rice" || x.attributes.AttributeValue == "Barley"));
    if(isValidCommodity && isValidId){
        let code = d.attributes.Code;
        let name = d.attributes.Name;
        let unit = d.AttributeList.Attribute.find(x => x.attributes.AttributeName == 'unit');
        ans.push({ "code" : code, "description" : name, "unit" : unit.attributes.AttributeValue });
    }
});

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: in your code where you are checking coditions which I mentioned in question. "AttributeName" is "id" and AttributeValue is "PROD" and "AttributeName" is "commodity" and AttributeValue is "Rice" or "Barley".? –

Comment: your code is giving me 3 elements but as per conditions I mentioned in question it should give me only two elements

Comment: Got your point and updated the answer. Hope it helps.